# Space of measurable function

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X=\{f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{F}, f ~measurable~function,\int_{0}^{1} |f(x)|^xdx<\infty\}$ be a set with metric $\rho(f,g)=\int_{0}^{1} |f(x)-g(x)|^xdx$. It looks like $L^p[0,1], 0<p<1$ space, but it is not. Exist any name of this space? 
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure $\rho(f,g)$ is a _metric_?

Comment: @metamorphy yes, I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called [Variable Exponent Lebesgue Spaces](http://www.crm.cat/en/Publications/Publications/2011/Pr1093.pdf). The link is to pdf notes by Cruz Uribe.

Comment: Many thanks ! I was looking for this spaces.